# mootools document.getelement is not a function

Tags: javascript, joomla, mootools, joomla-extensions

I'm trying to convert a Joomla 1.5 plugin to Joomla 2.5 plugin. As this plugin is runnning, Firebug says `TypeError: document.getElement is not a function.
Here is my code....

```
   var btn = document.getElement("#imageForm fieldset div [onclick=\"\"]");
                        console.log(btn);
                        if (btn.getAttribute("onclick").indexOf("ImageManager") > -1 )
                        {
                            if (typeof window.parent.'.$request['rewrite_function'].' === "function")
                            {
                                btn.setAttribute("onclick",btn.getAttribute("onclick").replace("ImageManager.onok()","window.parent.'.$request['rewrite_function'].'()"))
                            }
                        }
```

I have been stuck on this for hours now and I can't get it to work. Could you please tell me what is wrong with this javascript or atleast point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure Mootools is loaded?

Comment: Are you sure these Mootools methods exist? Seems you want to use $$ and get/setProperty.

Comment: @Bergi   Yes and Yes i have checked `Mootols-core.js` and those methods exists.

Comment: Hm, I can't find them in [the docs here](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element)

Comment: if you go into firebug or inspector, and type into console `document.getElement`, does it return a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had this issue when I was trying to use jquery and mootools on the same page.  I solved the problem by adding jquery's no conflict at the top of my html and whenever I made a jquery call, I used the $j variable I created instead of the shortcut $:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    var $j = jQuery;
  </script>
```